# What should a true RMS Voltage meter read on the load side of a zero fire SCR?

Tags: solid-state-relay, rms, scr

I have a 3 phase zero fire SCR/SSR set that has 480V input. I put my Fluke 289 (which is a tRMS meter) across the different phases on the load side. Then adjusted the output. The voltage read ~470V from 0 to full output. I also switched my Meter to measure frequency and it read 59Hz regardless of the SCR output. Is this the result I should expect or is something wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have a load connected to the output of the SSR set?  If not, the snubber capacitors that are usually connected across these devices will pass a small amount of AC current.  This is enough for your meter (which has a high input impedance) to read the full input voltage.

Comment: No I don't actually. I'll have to hook a load up to it tomorrow at try it.

Comment: Is it blown?  Semiconductors usually fail short-circuit.  Also, as @DwayneReid said, SCR's need some extra parts around them to make sure that they actually stay off when they're supposed to (the snubber network, which includes a resistor and a capacitor, at minimum), and these parts will "leak" a bit.  With no load, that leakage looks an awful lot like "on".

Comment: The answer to this was it needed a load. However meter doesn't give me a steady voltage reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is, most SCRs have capacitors in them. They need a load to bring the voltage down.

After I added a load to the output I got a proper reading on my RMS voltmeter.